# Proof that $g(z) = \int_0^1 f(t)e^{tz} \, dt$ is entire

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be a complex and continuous function on $[0,1]$. We'll define $g(z) = \int_0^1 f(t)e^{tz} \, dt $. Prove that $g(z)$ is an entire function.

Comment: Have you tried the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Comment: Morera's theorem seems to do it pretty quickly.  See my answer below.

Comment: You may differentiate under the integral sign.

Comment: @Christian Maybe a _proof_ that one may differentiate under the integral sign is just about what is being asked for here.

Answer (score 12):

[Morera's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem) implies that if for every circle $C$ in the complex plane,
$$
\int_C g(z) \; dz = 0
$$
then $g$ is entire.  To find that integral, first write
$$\int_C g(z) \; dz = \int_C\int_0^1 f(t)e^{tz} \; dt\; dz.$$
Now we're integrating continuous functions over compact sets, so everything in sight is Lebesgue-integrable and Fubini's theorem can be used to get
$$
\int_C\int_0^1 f(t)e^{tz} \; dt\; dz=\int_0^1 \int_C f(t) e^{tz} \; dz\;dt = \int_0^1\left(f(t)\int_C e^{tz} \; dz \right) \; dt.
$$
The inner integral is $0$ because it is the integral of an entire function around a circle.  So the whole thing is $0$ and the conclusion from Morera's theorem is just what is needed.

Comment: Michael, if you dont mind, how did you get that $$\int_C g(z) \; dz = \int_C\int_0^1 f(t)e^{tz} \; dt\; dz?$$

Comment: @Q.matin : It was explicitly stated in the original question above that $g(z)=\int_0^1 f(t) e^{tz}\,dt$.  In order to see whether Morera's theorem is applicable, we consider $\int_C g(z)\,dz$.

Answer (score 2):

If you write $f=f_1+\sqrt{-1}f_2$ where $f_1, f_2$ are continuous function on $[0,1]$ and $z=x+\sqrt{-1}y$, then 
$$g(z)=g(x,y)=\int_0^1\big(f_1(t)+\sqrt{-1}f_2(t)\big)e^{tx}\big(\cos(ty)+\sqrt{-1}\sin(ty)\big)dt.$$ Therefore the real part $u(x,y)$ and the imaginary part $v(x,y)$ of $g(x,y)$ are given by
$$u(x,y)=\int_0^1e^{tx}\big(f_1(t)\cos(ty)-f_2(t)\sin(ty)\big)dt$$
and
$$v(x,y)=\int_0^1e^{tx}\big(f_1(t)\sin(ty)+f_2(t)\cos(ty)\big)dt.$$
Then you can check easily that $u$ and $v$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann condition: $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$ for all $z=x+\sqrt{-1}y\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: +1. Note: "Leibniz integral rule" is of use in checking the conditions.

Comment: Why not check complex differentiability directly? Since you're going to differentiate under the integral sign anyway, I don't see the need for splitting into real and imaginary parts.

Comment: @t.b. yeap, that's another way to do it.

Comment: @matt oh yes, you are right.